# How to Show Icon on TabNavigator in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

**Hello Programmers,**

I have some issue with **React Navigation**,
I'm using **createBottomTabNavigator** to do Tab Navigator, but the icon it does not appear!
and then replace the icon with the image it's work correctly and it's not the issue with the react native vector icon because I use them in other screen and it's work,

#### Version

"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0"

"react-navigation": "^3.0.8"

#### Screen

[image: Home]

Other Screen to use the RN vector Icon

[image: Other Screen to use the RN vector Icon]

#### My Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import Search from "./src/screen/Search";
import Home from "./src/screen/Home";
import Locations from "./src/screen/Locations";

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Home",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Image
            source={require("./assets/rainy.png")}
            style={{ width: 26, height: 26, tintColor: tintColor }}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Search",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
          <Icon name="ios-search" size={25} color="#4F8EF7" />;
        }
      }
    },
    Locations: {
      screen: Locations,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Location",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
          <Icon name="ios-map" size={25} color="#4F8EF7" />;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: true,
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 14
      },
      style: {}
    },
    navigationOptions: {
      tabVisiable: true,
      activeTintColor: "red",
      animationEnabled: true
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: NOW it's Work :D, I just Add **return** :D   `tabBarIcon: () => {
          return <Icon size={20} name="ios-map" color={"red"} />;
        }`

Comment: oh! I had not seen this, also instead of braces put parentheses in this function to say that you are returning a JSX   

tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="ios-search" size={25} color="#4F8EF7" />;
)

Comment: @BrayanSalazar I'm really doing as JSX but it does not work just the **return** showing the icon, I don't know why!

Comment: What I was saying is that the first icon worked because it didn't have a `return` and it was in (). and the other two were between {} then it was a `function` and that's because you have put a `return`.

Comment: Oh, that's right thank you man for explaining :D

Answer (score 4):

you can use MaterialCommunityIcons like this :

```
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

<Tab.Screen
    name="Feed"
    component={Feed}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
      ),
    }}
  />
```

You can find more info here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Answer (score 1):

you can try define the icon in `navigationOptions` this is docs example

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={horizontal ? 20 : 25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);
```

with routeName you can put the icon

```
   if (routeName === 'Home') {
     return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={horizontal ? 20 : 25} color={tintColor} />;
   }
```